# Riemann integral show $f(x)=g(x)$ for at least 1 $x$ in [a,b]

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f = \int_a^b g$. Show that there exists $x\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x) = g(x) $.

I want to assume not and then show that the integrals cannot be equal. but perhaps an argument on an upper or lower sums of both fuctions could find the point?

Comment: So, if you assume not, what do you infer about $f-g$?

Comment: If you have covered Mean Value Theorem for integrals, it's one line.

Comment: We havent but its in my textbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on $[a, b]$ such that
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\ dx = \int_a^b g(x)\ dx.
$$
Then
$$
\int_a^b f(x)-g(x)\ dx = 0.
$$
Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $f-g$ is continuous. Hence, if $f-g$ is never zero on $[a, b]$, then it must be strictly positive or negative on $[a, b]$. But then $\int_a^b f(x)-g(x)\ dx \neq 0$, which is a contradiction.